# Is JTA available in JavaSE?

Tags: java, jta

Is it possible to make distributed transactions in JavaSE? I've heard about Atomikos, but I'm curious if I can use just standard Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, JTA is a Java EE API, and implementations need to be provided by a container or library.

Some implementations:

- [JOTM](http://jotm.ow2.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome)
- [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/Main/TransactionsEssentials) (open source version)
- [Bitronix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Home)
- [SimpleJTA](http://simplejta.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: and what can you advise from libraries?

Comment: @damluar I've only used Atomikos and JOTM, and neither for some time--I don't know enough to have any preferences.